# How can I increment a DateTime object to find the next Tuesday?

Tags: php, datetime

I'm trying to use the DateTime class to find some dates. I use the DateTime::modify order to find the next Tuesday, and it works. But if I try to find another time the next Tuesday, I always get the same date. What I'm doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2015-04-01');
echo $date->format('d/m/Y') . "\n";

for ($n = 0; $n < 10; $n++) {
  $date = $date->modify("first Tuesday of +1 week");
  echo $date->format('d/m/Y') . "\n";
}
```

And here is the output:

```
01/04/2015
14/04/2015
14/04/2015
14/04/2015
14/04/2015
14/04/2015
14/04/2015
14/04/2015
14/04/2015
14/04/2015
14/04/2015
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use "next Tuesday" without +1 week:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2015-04-01');
echo $date->format('d/m/Y') . "\n";

for ($n = 0; $n < 10; $n++) {
  $date->modify("next Tuesday");
  echo $date->format('d/m/Y') . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
01/04/2015
07/04/2015
14/04/2015
21/04/2015
28/04/2015
05/05/2015
12/05/2015
19/05/2015
26/05/2015
02/06/2015
09/06/2015
```

BTW, you don't need to assign result of `modify()` to a variable as it actually modifies the object rather than returning modified date.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to pass week number dynamically,

```
 $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2015-04-01');
    echo $date->format('d/m/Y') . "\n";

    for ($n = 0; $n < 10; $n++) {
      $date = $date->modify("first Tuesday of +".$n." week");
      echo $date->format('d/m/Y') . "\n";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this works with this example, but not in the real code I'm using. It's a function and it's called some times, and every time should return the next Tuesday (or the needed day).